# Invalid JSON Request + Json Request for WEBAPI C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am consuming WEBAPI and sending JSON Request along with Headers... When I saw my request in Fiddler I am getting 400 error - Bad Request.

I am using below method to post data :

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage PostData(string Path, string request, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestfulURL"]);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in headers.Keys)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }
        return client.PostAsJsonAsync(string.Concat(client.BaseAddress, UriPath), myrequest).Result;
    }
```

When I see in fiddler I am seeing   Request as

"{\"products\":[{\"prodID\":null,\"CategoryCode\":{\"codeValue\":\"humanresources\",\"shortName\":null,\"longName\":null}....

Not sure what the error is ? is having \" -- backslash causing the error ??

Comment: @spender myrequest  --  "{"products":[{"prodID":null,"CategoryCode":{"codeValue":"humanresources","shortName":null,"longName":null}....     when I sent request it didn't had any backslashh..

Comment: Don't worry about the backslashes. That's just for escaping the quotes. You should investigate the server side code. For some reason it doesn't understand the json you are sending.

Comment: @venerik I realized that in the method client. PostAsJsonAsync(string.Concat(client.BaseAddress, UriPath), myrequest).Result;   --- I am serailizing the .NET object to JSON and sending as "myrequest" --- but  I realized that PostAsJsonAsync method does (serailization) internally and I need to pass .NET Object..  If I pass .NET Object with out serialization it's working fine... I am assuming that myrequest/content which I am sending through PostAsJsonAsync should  be a .NET Object ?